# payment method vanishes if i reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am making an eCommerce site during the checkout process at last step i wanna show the address and payment method and i works if follow the steps but if i reload the page the address is there but the payment method vanishes both are saved in local storage

```
const PlaceOrderScreen = () => {

const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)

return (
    <div>
        <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4 />
        <Row>
            <Col md={8}>
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Shipping Address</h2>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Shipping: </strong>
                            {cart.shippingAddress.address}, {cart.shippingAddress.city},
                            {' '}
                            {cart.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                            {' '}
                            {cart.shippingAddress.country}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Payment Method</h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Method: </strong>
                            {cart.paymentMethod}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
```

In the screenshot you can see there is data saved in local storage but it isnt shwing on screen  (the payment method) after i reload it.

[image]

Comment: You need to check the code where you initialise the state values when app loads. Check if you are setting initial value from localstorage or not for payment method.

Comment: yes i do set it from local storage as i said at first it shows the payment method but vanishes only when i reload it but the address dosent vanish